# TikZ: two figures corresponding to each other

Tags: tikz-pgf

Now I have not yet started making this picture, and I would like some pointers. 
Any method to produce the image is sufficient, alas I would prefer TikZ and perhaps `tkz-euclide` over `asympote` or similar

> A rope is 10 meters long. We cut the rope in half, where the first
>   part is made into a equilateral triangle and the second part is made
>   into a square.
>
> The part that is used for the triangle is x meters long.

[image: My preferred output]

What my problem is, is that I do not know how to change the size of the square accordingly to the triangle.

For example if I say that 2 meters goes to the triangle. How would I make TikZ know that 8 would go to the square?

Comment: You mean '8 would go to the *square*'?

Comment: yes =) sorry for the confusion

Comment: No problem, I edited it for you. Hope it's ok. `:)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}   
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}    
\begin{document}

\def\totallength{10}  

\foreach \len in {2,5,8} 
{%    
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A};
    \tkzDefPoint(\len/3,0){B};  
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[B](0.5,0){C}; 
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[C](\totallength/4-\len/4,0){D}; 
    \tkzDrawTriangle[equilateral](A,B)   
    \tkzDrawSquare(C,D) 
 \end{tikzpicture}\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice solution. You seem so good using tkz-euclide ^^ 
Are there any way to "force" these three results to be in one line? I am able to do it, splitting them up into minipages, but that seems like an ugly hack.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: I believe that Altermundus *wrote* tkz-euclide!

Comment: I know! He is one awesome guy!

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar, it should be enough to remove the `\par`.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I wrote `tkz-euclide` for mathematics teachers who do not have enough time to study `Tikz` and for me to avoid repetitive works but in other cases and in contexts, I recommend learning and working with `Tikz`. You can remove the `\par`to get results on the same line.

Answer (score 16):

`\pgfmathsetmacro` is your friend:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\totallength}{10}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% --- only edit the next ---
\pgfmathsetmacro{\trianglelength}{2}
% --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
\pgfmathsetmacro{\triangleside}{\trianglelength/3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\squarelength}{\totallength-\trianglelength}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\squareside}{\squarelength/4}
\draw (-0.1,0) -- ++(180:\triangleside) -- ++(60:\triangleside) -- cycle;
\draw (0.1,0) rectangle ++(\squareside,\squareside);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% --- only edit the next ---
\pgfmathsetmacro{\trianglelength}{5}
% --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
\pgfmathsetmacro{\triangleside}{\trianglelength/3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\squarelength}{\totallength-\trianglelength}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\squareside}{\squarelength/4}
\draw (-0.1,0) -- ++(180:\triangleside) -- ++(60:\triangleside) -- cycle;
\draw (0.1,0) rectangle ++(\squareside,\squareside);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% --- only edit the next ---
\pgfmathsetmacro{\trianglelength}{8}
% --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
\pgfmathsetmacro{\triangleside}{\trianglelength/3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\squarelength}{\totallength-\trianglelength}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\squareside}{\squarelength/4}
\draw (-0.1,0) -- ++(180:\triangleside) -- ++(60:\triangleside) -- cycle;
\draw (0.1,0) rectangle ++(\squareside,\squareside);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can write `\pgfmathsetmacro{\totallength}{10}` at the beginning of your code and outside the `tikzpicture environment`

Comment: In your example `\totallength` is not really used. Did you mean `\pgfmathsetmacro{\squarelength}{\totallength-\trianglelength}` instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro{\squarelength}{__10__-\trianglelength}`

Comment: @amorua: Of course! That's one silly error..